# How to read agent application data to azure sql using apim and logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have agent application which generating data which need to be pushed to azure sql using APIM and logic apps.

1. I have created agent application will post the data in json format
2. I have create blank api in Azure APIM with added API URL suffix (my-api) and operation as /data(post Method).

Now i was unable to proceed further , I have tried to access the api through test and postman i am getting
statusCode': 500, 'message': 'Internal server error'

Please help me what I am doing wrong , and logic app how to configure also.

Now i was unable to proceed further , I have tried to access the api through test and postman i am getting
statusCode': 500, 'message': 'Internal server error'

Comment: Provide some proper insight. You’re asking us to help and you’ve provided stuff all real information.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Logic App with the [`When a HTTP request is received`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint?tabs=consumption) trigger.

Step 2: In the API Management service select `APIs` → `+ Add API` → `Create from Azure resource` → `Logic App`.

[image]

Select your Logic App, enter a Display Name (user-friendly, can be changed later) and an API URL suffix (can be changed later as well). The API name is not that important; it will be generated automatically, though you can edit it before creating - it cannot be changed later.

[image]

The process is quite straightforward. You will be able to call your Logic App via the API Management service by sending a request to the Base URL + the API operation URL suffix, e.g. https://heregoesyourapimanagementservice.azure-api.net/test1/resource1